# http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: go, google-geocoding-api

I am using go to consume the google maps geocoding API, but I keep getting this error:

```
The HTTP request failed with error Get https://maps.googleapis.com /maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bangalore&key=KEY: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

The url in the error works fine in my browser and gives the appropriate response, but won't give what I want in the code snippet below:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main()  {
    key := "mysecretkey"
    location := "Bangalore"
    url := "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+location+"&key="+key
    fmt.Println("Starting the application...")
    response, err := http.Get(url)

    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    }else {
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(data))
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing https in URL to http

Comment: I end up getting this:`{
   "error_message" : "Requests to this API must be over SSL. Load the API with \"https://\" instead of \"http://\".",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}`

Comment: Something is wrong on your end. Your code works fine when I run it locally. What Go version are you on?

Comment: This is the output of `go version` :`go1.12.5 linux/amd64`

Comment: I tried to uninstall go, and then reinstall another version, this time go 1.9.3, but still same problem persists.

Comment: This should Just Work(tm). Are you using a proxy? And stick to Go 1.12. 1.9 isn't supported anymore.

Comment: YES. I am such a fool. Thanks @Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the proxy, which probably caused some certificate issues. Works fine without proxy .

Comment: Can you elaborate what changes you made, I get similar error. Is it because of golang version ?

Comment: This led me to look into the code and I saw that the Django settings had `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT`, `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`, and other related settings that seemed to be causing this issue. Removing them helped. The rest seemed to possibly be an issue with our nginx setup. Still working on it.

Answer (score -3):

Iam just change by `http.post("https://localhost:8080)` to `http.post("http://localhost:8080")`.
Just remove a `s` in `https`.
Its work :-)

Comment: Bad practice. Anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56488377/http-server-gave-http-response-to-https-client#comment99566026_56488377